# Return images from a method

Tags: c#

I'm having problems on this method that I'm working on to return images that have been added to the list so when its done all the pictures that have been added can be displayed on the PictureBox that I have. Right now the method just adds the images. So I would like the method to return all the images from the List so I can simply display them on the PictureBox. Any help or advice, I would be very thankful

```
private List<Image> CollectionOfPictures;

public Image ReturnPictures(List<Image> pics)
{
    foreach (Image image in pics)
    {
        CollectionOfPictures.Add(image);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a private field containing the images... couldn't you just reference that when attempting to show them?

Comment: ok i forgot to change it from void to Image sorry

Comment: So what are you trying to return here then ? Your method has a return type but no return statement.

Comment: yes thats what I need help on. I'm stuck there. I know how to add them but dont know how to return the images so that they can be displayed one by one on the pictureBox

Answer (score 0):

why cant you do this

```
public List<Image> ReturnPictures(List<Image> pics)
{
    return  pics;
}
```

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of calling the method in the first place.

Comment: yeah I agee but i do not really see the point of rewriting the images to private list you can make the method private  think he wants the method to return the list

Comment: yes i want all the images to be return so I can display all of them that has been added. Should I change from void to images instead

Comment: @Austin Smith yes it would make what you want i think

Comment: @M.Babcock that what i did in my answer is to show him that in order to return he needs not to use void but return type and he might folow certain gyideline in which he has to call return even though I agree it might not be need I guess it could be a comment

Comment: But it wont let me it says that Image is a abstract class I've tried a a couple of ways and didn't work. Will your method return the list of the images I thought I need a foreach loop to return every image added so they can be displayed

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple different options from what I see:

1. Expose your Image list to whatever it is that is drawing the images (aka make it public)
2. Lists are reference types so passing it by value should retain anything added to it if you can't do #1.

Or perhaps I'm over simplifying your problem. In which case I'd ask that you restate it.

---

Edit in response to your's:

The method you propose is illogical. A method that takes a list of images while returning only one without selecting which to return.

I believe you mean:

```
private List<Image> CollectionOfPictures;

public List<Image> ReturnPictures(List<Image> pics)
{
    foreach (Image image in pics)
    {
        CollectionOfPictures.Add(image);
    }
}
```

Which could better be represented as:

```
private List<Image> CollectionOfPictures;

public List<Image> ReturnPictures(List<Image> pics)
{
    return CollectionOfPictures.Concat(pics).ToList();
}
```

Or skip the method all together by using the Linq method directly.

Or to retain the list between calls:

```
private List<Image> CollectionOfPictures;

public List<Image> ReturnPictures(List<Image> pics)
{
    return (CollectionOfPictures = CollectionOfPictures.Concat(pics).ToList());
}
```

---

And without LINQ:

```
private List<Image> CollectionOfPictures;

public List<Image> ReturnPictures(List<Image> pics)
{
    foreach (Image image in pics)
    {
        CollectionOfPictures.Add(image);
    }

    return CollectionOfPictures;
}
```

Comment: Yes I want to display each image that has added one by one so I changed it from void to Image so it can return Images thats been added

Comment: Updated to reflect what I think you're looking for. If not, let me know.

Comment: I won't to return all not one. and I'm so sorry if I'm confusing you thank you so much for your help god bless you.

Comment: I'm implementing it now to see

Comment: No it doesn't solve it because it returns a list and not an        Images pictureBox2.Image = ImageDisplay.ReturnPictures(List<Image> pics); Can't implicitly convert list to image thats the error im getting now

Comment: Ok going back to your previous comment _I won't to return all not one._... Do you want one or all? And if all then how do you expect to meet the picture boxes expectation of only one image?

Comment: Not that way. I think what you're looking for is a way to weave the images in the list into a single image to be displayed in the picture box. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

if you'd be displaying them one by one you can just return the elements of CollectionOfPictures. 
I assume there would be a navigation to go back and forth between the pictures in the list? you could do something like

```
int currentIndex = 0
public Image getImage() {
return CollectionOfPictures[currentIndex];
}

public void nextPicture() {
//check if currentIndex < the length
currentIndex++;
}


public void prevPicture() {
//check if currentIndex >0

currentIndex--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
private List<Image> CollectionOfPictures;

public List<Image> ReturnPictures(List<Image> pics)
{
    CollectionOfPictures = new List<Image>();
    foreach (Image image in pics)
    {
        CollectionOfPictures.Add(image);
    }
    return CollectionOfPictures;
}
```

or simply

```
public List<Image> ReturnPictures(List<Image> pics)
{
    return  pics;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to edit your post. I went to edit mine and yours appeared in edit mode... it's been reverted now.

Comment: No it doesn't solve it because it returns a list and not an        Images pictureBox2.Image = ImageDisplay.ReturnPictures(List<Image> pics); Can't implicitly convert list to image thats the error im getting now

Comment: can you please share some more code.. how are you doing that..?